# How to get the name of the executables files in bash with ls

Tags: linux, bash, file, terminal, ls

I try to get the name of the executable files using ls -l. 
Then I tried to get the lines of ls -l which have a x using grep -w x but the result is not right : some executable files are missing (the .sh).

I just need the name of the executable files not the path but I don't know how ...

```
    user@user-K53TA:~/Bureau$ ls -l
total 52
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user   64 oct.   6 21:07 a.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   11 sept. 29 21:51 e.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  140 sept. 29 23:42 hi.sh
drwxrwxr-x 8 user user 4096 juil. 30 20:47 nerdtree-master
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  492 oct.   6 21:07 okk.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1543 oct.   6 21:07 ok.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  119 sept. 29 23:27 oo.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 8672 sept. 29 21:20 prog
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user  405 sept. 29 21:23 prog.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 sept. 29 21:58 rev
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 sept. 29 20:51 sublime

 user@user-K53TA:~/Bureau$ ls -l | grep -w x
drwxrwxr-x 8 user user 4096 juil. 30 20:47 nerdtree-master
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 8672 sept. 29 21:20 prog
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 sept. 29 20:51 sublime
```

Comment: is using `ls` mandatory? [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: no but i don't know another way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). This can be done with `find`.

```
find . -type f -perm /a+x
```

This finds files with any of the executable bits set: user, group, or other.

Answer (score 2):

Use find instead:

```
 find -executable
 find -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
 find -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -ls
```

Comment: Note that `-maxdepth` and `-executable` are non-standard extensions (work with GNU `find`, but not specified by POSIX). Also note that `-executable` can differ from `-perm /a+x`…

Answer (score 1):

One can use a `for` loop with glob expansion for discovering and manipulating file names. Observe:

```
#!/bin/sh 

for i in *
do # Only print discoveries that are executable files
   [ -f "$i" -a -x "$i" ] && printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer uses no `ls` at all:

`ls -l | grep -e '^...x'`